# cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I usually never have a problem with this step, but for some reason when I re set up my storyboard now I have an issue with this part of my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    (cell as! TableViewCell).usernameLabel.text = friendsArray[indexPath.row] as String


    return cell
}
```

I have done all of the obvious stuff like making sure the cell identifier is "Cell".

My error is this:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1094ada18) to 'YOpub.TableViewCell' (0x106620410).

EDIT: Problem was I had         self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell") in my didLoad function. After removing this line my code worked again.

Comment: What's your *exact* issue?  I know *my* issue is use of `as!`

Comment: I get this error: Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10f61ea18) to 'YOpub.TableViewCell'

Comment: Have you changed the Cell type in Storyboard to TableViewCell?

Comment: Yea I did this. Any other suggestions maybe?

Comment: Is that a compiler error? or a crash?

Comment: My answer was right. Please accept it.

Answer (score 12):

- You may have forgotten to tell the storyboard that this cell *is* a TableViewCell. Select the prototype cell and set the Custom Class in the Identity inspector.
- You may have called `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. If so, delete that call; it actually *prevents* us from getting the cell from the storyboard.
- You are calling `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. That is a big mistake. You should call `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Comment: I did that. This was not the issue .

Comment: I did that. This was not the issue . Im sure the answer is so small Im just not positive what it is I thought I covered all the bases correctly.  Matt I can tell your great with swift since you wrote the book on it! What else should I check for?

Comment: Well, I assure you that the problem is that you are receiving a UITableViewCell, not a TableViewCell. - Tell me this: did you, by any chance, implement `registerClass:...` or `registerNib:...`? If so, that's a mistake; it _prevents_ us from getting the cell from the storyboard.

Comment: By the way, if this project is not too private, I'm happy to take a look at it for you. I promise not to look at anything much except for the storyboard and the table view controller code.

Comment: I had done         self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell") but now that I removed it the table works perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: `I had done self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")` Comment it out. But also see my changed answer. You must call `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Comment: Yep, registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier was the problem!! Go figure

Comment: @user1366265 I don't have to go figure. I know what `registerClass:` does - it _prevents_ use of the storyboard, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason,May be in Identity inspector module is different then your project name  .  [image]