# Swift: Strange downcasting failure

Tags: ios, swift

I have a rather strange case of downcasting failure that I cannot understand.

I have almost identical code in two `UITableViewController`s. `ProjectTableViewController` displays list of `Project`, and its datasource is `[Project]`. `NewsfeedsTableViewController` displays list of `Newsfeed`, but `Newsfeed` can contain different types of source data, including `Project`.

Depending on the type of the source data, each cell of `NewsfeedsTableViewController` is downcasted to appropriate subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

`ProjectTableViewCell` a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and is used in both `ProjectTableViewController` and `NewsfeedsTableViewController`.

Now the interesting thing is, the code works without issue in `ProjectTableViewController` but crashes in `NewsfeedsTableViewController`, giving following error message:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x102e68128) to 'sample_app.ProjectTableViewCell' (0x1010ce6d0).
```

I have following codes in each class:

```
ProjectTableViewController.swift

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let project = projects[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProjectTableViewCell") as! ProjectTableViewCell

    cell.projectTitle.text = project.title
    cell.projectKeywords.text = project.keywords

    return cell
}


NewsfeedsTableViewController.swift

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let newsfeed = self.newsfeeds[indexPath.row]
    switch newsfeed.newsfeedableType {
    case "Project":
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsfeedTableViewCell") as! ProjectTableViewCell
        let source = newsfeed.newsfeedable as! Project
        cell.projectTitle.text = source.title
        cell.projectKeywords.text = source.keywords
        return cell

    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsfeedTableViewCell")!
        cell.textLabel!.text = newsfeed.newsfeedableType + String(newsfeed.id)
        return cell
    }
}
```

I would love to understand what's causing this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429269/cast-value-of-type-uitableviewcell-to-custom-cell or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812168/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uitableviewcell-to-appname-customcellname would help you bit

Comment: @ViralSavaj thanks! those links got me to look into storyboard again... and the issue was there!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by adding another prototype cell of `ProjectTableViewCell` to the `NewsfeedsTableViewController`, and using it to display `Newsfeed` with `Project` as source.

Which means I will have to add prototype cells for all the source data types, and then configure them on the storyboard. I'm not looking forward to doing that.

I thought I could duck-type through this all, but I guess Swift does not work like that.